# Convert NSDecimalNumber to NSDecimal

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am using the CorePlot library in order to create some charts. While I am working on it I have come to the need to change the X-axis property `Xaxis.MajorIntervalLength`, which is an NSDecimal.

I tried, but I cannot create an `NSDecimal` number. I can only create an `NSDecimalNumber`, and when I try to assign it to the property it throws this error:

```
Assigning to NSDecimal from incompatible type NSDecimalNumber
```

I know that NSdecimal is not an Objective-C class anymore, but I guess but I need to use it somehow!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can ask your `NSDecimalNumber` for its [`decimalValue`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDecimalNumber_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDecimalNumber/decimalValue):

```
plot.property = myDecimalNumber.decimalValue;
```

Comment: I know I was missing something there. thank you very much it worked :)